# In php cron syntax url i have two parameters passed but it gets one parameter

Tags: php

this my url cron syntax

1.* 30 * * wget http://myappone.com/universitysaver/scripts /signUpForm3.php?userId=49crbrGzdPk3&value=1.99

1. its gets only one argument that is first argument
2. the second argument its not displayed
3. iam using $_REQUEST['userId'];
4. and $_REQUEST['value'];
5. and another thing is iam changing the values first argument is **value** second argument is **userId** its displayes **value** but it not display **userId**
6. 30 * * wget http://myappone.com/universitysaver/scripts /signUpForm3.php?**userId**=49crbrGzdPk3&**value**=1.99
7. its get only first argument the second argument  its not get
8. i want to get two arguments how can i get
9. please help me
10. thanks for advance

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET);` you may need to encode your query string

Answer (score 1):

In bash & is special character and tells the shell to put the process in the background, so nothing after the & is read. you need to escape your string

```
30 * * * * wget http://myappone.com/universitysaver/scripts /signUpForm3.php?userId=49crbrGzdPk3\&value=1.99
```

or

```
30 * * * * wget "http://myappone.com/universitysaver/scripts /signUpForm3.php?userId=49crbrGzdPk3&value=1.99"
```